# Which information on my profile is visible to others?

Tags: support, profile-page, privacy

When editing my user profile (name, date of birth, etc.), how can I tell which information can be seen by other users (publicly visible) and what is only used by the system (and how it's used)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The easiest way is to open up your profile in an incognito browser session.

Things that are visible to everybody:

- website
- location
- how old your account is
- when you were last on the site
- the "About me" section

Things visible to ♦ moderators (of the site where your profile belongs to) only:

- real name <sup>1</sup>
- email <sup>1</sup>
- your IP address <sup>1</sup>
- how many days you visited the site (and your current consecutive visits streak)
- all the names you used in the last 90 days

---

<sup>1</sup> Moderator access to this information is logged.

Comment: I assume moderators can also see the calendar when clicking the value of "visited"?

Comment: @Arjan Yes. Or at least it works for me and I hope it's not an employee quirk. :)

Comment: Can moderators see the "old" real name even after the user changes it in their profile?

Comment: @MaskedMan Display names yes, real names no.

Comment: **real name + email + IP**. How can you detect if a mod used this information to target a user off-site? Assuming the mod took precautions to make the "button click" look justifiable.

Comment: @Fermiparadox, the mods have to sign [an agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) before getting their diamonds.  Misusing PII can potentially lead to law suits against the mods. (not to mention that even accidentally revealing PII is enough to fire a mod, and has happened once in the past)

Comment: If someone asks a question in an incognito window, is the IP still recorded?

Comment: @fasterthanlight Yes. We don't know if you're asking from an incognito window or not, and you still have to either log into an account or create an "unregistered" one to post (in which case you'll lose access to it once you close the incognito window since it's entirely cookie-based).