# Can other users see your IP Address?

Tags: support, ip-address

I am wondering if it is possible for other users to see your IP Address, or to see the IP of the person that submitted the post.

Comment: No. It is not...

Comment: As far as I know moderators can see IP

Answer (score 8):

Here's a [list of who can see what in your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149636/who-can-see-what-in-my-profile/149637#149637)

Other than moderators (and people working for SE) - no one can. Moderators  have to agree to a [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), and have their viewing of IP addresses logged.

So no, it is *typically* not possible to do either unless you have a good reason to.

Also, IP addresses on their own are pretty boring.

Comment: You obviously haven't seen my IP address ...

Comment: Eh. Octets. The lot of em

Comment: @rene does it have a 666 in it? :)

Comment: Its all 666. Which is odd

Comment: @JourneymanGeek <pedant>666 is even</pedant> ;)